# Confidence interval of a half-circular parameter

Tags: confidence-interval, mathematical-statistics, variance

I am modelling two dimensional ovals on a two dimensional plane. Each oval is defined by five parameters, namely `x, y, s1, s2, t` where `x` and `y` are its position on the plane, `s1` and `s2` are length of its long and short axis respectively and `t` is the angle that the long axis of the oval makes with the y-axis i.e. `t` is the direction of the oval. As the ovals are symmetric `t = t+pi` so, `t` is set to a range of -0.5*pi to 0.5*pi.

To acquire the mean and 95% confidence interval of most of these parameters bootstrapping is used and the 2.5 50 and 97.5 percentile are taken. However, as `t` is a circular parameter it may occur that some of the outcomes of the bootstrap are slightly above -0.5*pi and others are slightly below 0.5*pi. This prevents the use of a percentiles for the confidence interval.

While a mean can easily be acquired by converting the angles to a cartesian plane and doing the math from there, I am clueless as to how to find a measure for 95% confidence or a standard error.